# Crontab job is failing and I dont know why

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I set up a script to update my computer and it is set up to run hourly but when I check the status of the cron job it shows the jobs are failing and I don't know why.

Below is the shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

It is in home/myname/bin/update.sh and when I go to that and run

```
./update.sh
```

The script runs and it works properly but in the crontab job listed below isn't working.

```
@hourly /home/myname/bin/update.sh
```

It is a sudo crontab job so I figured it would work but when I check its status I see.

```
sudo crontab -l
Jul 17 08:16:04 HP-Z820-Workstation sudo[1393]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation fail
Jul 17 08:16:04 HP-Z820-Workstation sudo[1393]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not id
Jul 17 11:00:01 HP-Z820-Workstation sudo[12992]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation fai
Jul 17 11:00:01 HP-Z820-Workstation sudo[12992]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not i
Jul 17 11:00:01 HP-Z820-Workstation sudo[12994]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation fai
Jul 17 11:00:01 HP-Z820-Workstation sudo[12994]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not i
Jul 17 12:00:01 HP-Z820-Workstation sudo[15073]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation fai
Jul 17 12:00:01 HP-Z820-Workstation sudo[15073]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not i
Jul 17 12:00:01 HP-Z820-Workstation sudo[15075]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation fai
Jul 17 12:00:01 HP-Z820-Workstation sudo[15075]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not i
```

So if anyone has an insight I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If you put the script in `root` user's crontab you do not need the `sudo` in your script.

Comment: Alrighty. I originally didn't have it in the root crontab so I didn't even think about taking it out, thanks!

Comment: I have adjusted the crontab but now it doesn't run, any idea? The script is the same but the sudo's are taken out and now when I use `service cron status` it says it's active but it has yet to update a single time and at the bottom shows `Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.` @FedonKadifeli any idea?

Comment: I would recommend to redirect script's *stdout* and *stderr* to files and see what happens when the script is executed in one hour.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Can you give an example with the information I provided above?

Comment: Update crontab like this `@hourly /home/myname/bin/update.sh >>/tmp/1 2>>/tmp/2`

Comment: Okay, I just did that verbatim. What exactly is this supposed to change or what does it mean?

Comment: It is still showing the same thing as in `Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.` but it also is still active and running.

Comment: The contents of the files `/tmp/1` and `/tmp/2` may contain something useful.

Comment: So it looks like this still isn't quite working. Any ideas?